# Multiplication structure of $E^∞$ and $H^*$

Tags: algebraic-topology, fiber-bundles, spectral-sequences

Given a fiber bundle $F→E→B$. Suppose the associated spectral sequence convergence and $E^∞$ isomophic to $H^*(E)$ as abelian groups.

My question is when they are isomorphic as rings?Do we have any general theory to answer this?